# RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (1x1792 and 2048x1) in Google Colab in Windows (Python code)

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, neural-network, runtime-error, google-colaboratory

I am trying to train a neural network to predict one value using 3D images of different cases as input. According to the configuration parameters, the size of input images that I pass to the neural network is (8,1,96,96,96) and the output is a scalar value.

When I run this cell...

```
# Init model
model = BrainAgeCNN().to(config.device)

config.lr = 0.01
config.betas = (0.9, 0.999)
config.num_steps = 1400


# Init optimizers
optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(
    model.parameters(),
    lr=config.lr,
    betas=config.betas
)
# Init tensorboard
writer = TensorboardLogger(config.log_dir, config)
# Train
model, step = train(
    config=config,
    model=model,
    optimizer=optimizer,
    train_loader=dataloaders['train'],
    val_loader=dataloaders['val'],
    writer=writer
)
```

This is the error that I obtain just at the end of the training, but during the training I do not get any error:

```
Training:   0%|          | 0/50 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Training:   2%|▏         | 1/50 [00:00<00:16,  2.89it/s]
Training:   4%|▍         | 2/50 [00:00<00:17,  2.79it/s]
Training:   6%|▌         | 3/50 [00:00<00:14,  3.33it/s]
Training:   8%|▊         | 4/50 [00:01<00:12,  3.67it/s]
Training:  10%|█         | 5/50 [00:01<00:11,  3.87it/s]
Training:  12%|█▏        | 6/50 [00:01<00:10,  4.02it/s]
Training:  14%|█▍        | 7/50 [00:01<00:10,  4.12it/s]
Training:  16%|█▌        | 8/50 [00:02<00:10,  4.15it/s]
Training:  18%|█▊        | 9/50 [00:02<00:09,  4.21it/s]
Training:  20%|██        | 10/50 [00:02<00:09,  4.23it/s]
Training:  22%|██▏       | 11/50 [00:02<00:09,  4.29it/s]
Training:  24%|██▍       | 12/50 [00:03<00:08,  4.26it/s]
Training:  26%|██▌       | 13/50 [00:03<00:08,  4.30it/s]
Training:  28%|██▊       | 14/50 [00:03<00:08,  4.33it/s]
Training:  30%|███       | 15/50 [00:03<00:08,  4.34it/s]
Training:  32%|███▏      | 16/50 [00:03<00:07,  4.30it/s]
Training:  34%|███▍      | 17/50 [00:04<00:07,  4.30it/s]
Training:  36%|███▌      | 18/50 [00:04<00:07,  4.31it/s]
Training:  38%|███▊      | 19/50 [00:04<00:07,  4.33it/s]
Training:  40%|████      | 20/50 [00:04<00:06,  4.33it/s]
Training:  42%|████▏     | 21/50 [00:05<00:06,  4.35it/s]
Training:  44%|████▍     | 22/50 [00:05<00:06,  4.34it/s]
Training:  46%|████▌     | 23/50 [00:05<00:06,  4.36it/s]
Training:  48%|████▊     | 24/50 [00:05<00:05,  4.37it/s]
Training:  50%|█████     | 25/50 [00:06<00:05,  4.37it/s]
Training:  52%|█████▏    | 26/50 [00:06<00:05,  4.36it/s]
Training:  54%|█████▍    | 27/50 [00:06<00:05,  4.38it/s]
Training:  56%|█████▌    | 28/50 [00:06<00:05,  4.36it/s]
Training:  58%|█████▊    | 29/50 [00:06<00:04,  4.34it/s]
Training:  60%|██████    | 30/50 [00:07<00:04,  4.35it/s]
Training:  62%|██████▏   | 31/50 [00:07<00:04,  4.34it/s]
Training:  64%|██████▍   | 32/50 [00:07<00:04,  4.32it/s]
Training:  66%|██████▌   | 33/50 [00:07<00:03,  4.29it/s]
Training:  68%|██████▊   | 34/50 [00:08<00:03,  4.23it/s]
Training:  70%|███████   | 35/50 [00:08<00:03,  4.26it/s]
Training:  72%|███████▏  | 36/50 [00:08<00:03,  4.25it/s]
Training:  74%|███████▍  | 37/50 [00:08<00:03,  4.25it/s]
Training:  76%|███████▌  | 38/50 [00:09<00:02,  4.27it/s]
Training:  78%|███████▊  | 39/50 [00:09<00:02,  4.25it/s]
Training:  80%|████████  | 40/50 [00:09<00:02,  4.22it/s]
Training:  82%|████████▏ | 41/50 [00:09<00:02,  4.27it/s]
Training:  84%|████████▍ | 42/50 [00:09<00:01,  4.24it/s]
Training:  86%|████████▌ | 43/50 [00:10<00:01,  4.25it/s]
Training:  88%|████████▊ | 44/50 [00:10<00:01,  4.25it/s]
Training:  90%|█████████ | 45/50 [00:10<00:01,  4.27it/s]
Training:  92%|█████████▏| 46/50 [00:10<00:00,  4.27it/s]
Training:  94%|█████████▍| 47/50 [00:11<00:00,  4.27it/s]
Training:  96%|█████████▌| 48/50 [00:11<00:00,  4.28it/s]
Training:  98%|█████████▊| 49/50 [00:11<00:00,  4.27it/s]
Training: 100%|██████████| 50/50 [00:11<00:00,  4.25it/s]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-ba791e9bf3a2> in <module>
     14     train_loader=dataloaders['train'],
     15     val_loader=dataloaders['val'],
---> 16     writer=writer
     17 )

5 frames
<ipython-input-29-98abf7b06208> in train(config, model, optimizer, train_loader, val_loader, writer)
     41                     model,
     42                     val_loader,
---> 43                     config,
     44                 )
     45 

<ipython-input-29-98abf7b06208> in validate(model, val_loader, config, show_plot)
     76 
     77         with torch.no_grad(): # Context-manager that disabled gradient calculation
---> 78             loss, pred = model.train_step(x, y, return_prediction=True)
     79         avg_val_loss.add(loss.item())
     80         preds.append(pred.cpu())

/content/ai-in-medicine-practical-session1/models.py in train_step(self, imgs, labels, return_prediction)
    112         :return pred
    113         """
--> 114         pred = torch.squeeze(self.forward(imgs.float()))  # (N)
    115 
    116         # ----------------------- ADD YOUR CODE HERE --------------------------

/content/ai-in-medicine-practical-session1/models.py in forward(self, imgs)
     93 
     94         x = x.view(-1, x.shape[0]*x.shape[1]*x.shape[2]*x.shape[3]*x.shape[4])
---> 95         pred = self.relu1_5(self.fc1(x))
     96 
     97         # ------------------------------- END ---------------------------------

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1128         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1129                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1130             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1131         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1132         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py in forward(self, input)
    112 
    113     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 114         return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
    115 
    116     def extra_repr(self) -> str:

RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (1x1792 and 2048x1)
```

According to what I have seen in the parameters of the model. This model supposedly trains well and it seems that I set the batch size to 8. However, at the end of training this value changes to 7 (I do not know why), and gives me the error above.

This is the function for training:

```
def train(config, model, optimizer, train_loader, val_loader, writer):
    model.train()
    step = 0
    pbar = tqdm(total=config.val_freq,
                desc=f'Training') # Progress bar
    avg_loss = AvgMeter() # Computes and stores the average and current value.


    while True:
        for x, y in train_loader:
            x = x.to(config.device) 
            y = y.to(config.device)
            pbar.update(1) # Update progress bar 1 value

            # Training step
            optimizer.zero_grad() # Sets the gradients of all optimized torch.Tensor s to zero
            loss = model.train_step(x, y) # Calculate the loss
            loss.backward() # Computes dloss/dx for every parameter x which has requires_grad=True (x.grad += dloss/dx)
            optimizer.step() # Updates the value of x using the gradient x.grad (x += -lr * x.grad)
            # optimizer.zero_grad() clears x.grad for every parameter x in the optimizer. It’s important to call this before loss.backward(), 
            # otherwise you’ll accumulate the gradients from multiple passes.

            avg_loss.add(loss.detach().item())
            # .detach() will return a tensor, which is detached from the computation graph, while .item() will return the Python scalar

            # Increment step
            step += 1

            if step % config.log_freq == 0 and not step % config.val_freq == 0:
                train_loss = avg_loss.compute()
                writer.log({'train/loss': train_loss}, step=step)

            # Validate and log at validation frequency
            if step % config.val_freq == 0:
                # Reset avg_loss
                train_loss = avg_loss.compute()
                avg_loss = AvgMeter()

                # Get validation results
                val_results = validate(
                    model,
                    val_loader,
                    config,
                )

                # Print current performance
                print(f"Finished step {step} of {config.num_steps}. "
                      f"Train loss: {train_loss} - "
                      f"val loss: {val_results['val/loss']:.4f} - "
                      f"val MAE: {val_results['val/MAE']:.4f}")

                # Write to tensorboard
                writer.log(val_results, step=step)

                # Reset progress bar
                pbar = tqdm(total=config.val_freq, desc='Training')

            if step >= config.num_steps:
                print(f'\nFinished training after {step} steps\n')
                return model, step


def validate(model, val_loader, config, show_plot=False):
    model.eval()
    # model.eval() is a kind of switch for some specific layers/parts of the model that behave differently during training 
    # and inference (evaluating) time. For example, Dropouts Layers, BatchNorm Layers etc. You need to turn off them during model 
    # evaluation, and .eval() will do it for you. In addition, the common practice for evaluating/validation is using torch.no_grad() 
    # in pair with model.eval() to turn off gradients computation

    avg_val_loss = AvgMeter()
    preds = []
    targets = []
    for x, y in val_loader:
        x = x.to(config.device)
        y = y.to(config.device)

        with torch.no_grad(): # Context-manager that disabled gradient calculation
            loss, pred = model.train_step(x, y, return_prediction=True)
        avg_val_loss.add(loss.item())
        preds.append(pred.cpu())
        targets.append(y.cpu())

    # torch.cat() Concatenates the given sequence of seq tensors in the given dimension
    # All tensors must either have the same shape (except in the concatenating dimension) or be empty
    preds = torch.cat(preds)
    targets = torch.cat(targets)
    mae = mean_absolute_error(preds, targets)
    f = plot_results(preds, targets, show_plot)
    model.train()
    return {
        'val/loss': avg_val_loss.compute(),
        'val/MAE': mae,
        'val/MAE_plot': f
    }


def plot_results(preds: Tensor, targets: Tensor, show_plot: bool = False):
    # Compute the mean absolute error
    mae_test = mean_absolute_error(preds, targets)
    # Sort preds and targets to ascending targets
    sort_inds = targets.argsort() # It returns an array of indices along the given axis of the same shape as the input array, in sorted order
    targets = targets[sort_inds].numpy() # Converts a tensor object into an numpy.ndarray object
    preds = preds.view(targets.shape)
    preds = preds[sort_inds].numpy() # Converts a tensor object into an numpy.ndarray object

    f = plt.figure()
    plt.plot(targets, targets, 'r.')
    plt.plot(targets, preds, '.')
    plt.plot(targets, targets + mae_test, 'gray')
    plt.plot(targets, targets - mae_test, 'gray')
    plt.suptitle('Mean Average Error')
    plt.xlabel('True Age')
    plt.ylabel('Age predicted')
    if show_plot:
        plt.show()
    return f
```

This is the neural network that I am using for training. It is a neural network with 3D convolutions, batch normalizations, ReLU() and fully connected layers at the end.

```
from typing import Optional
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

from torch import Tensor


class BrainAgeCNN(nn.Module):
    """
    The BrainAgeCNN predicts the age given a brain MR-image.
    """
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        self.loss = torch.nn.MSELoss()


        # Feel free to also add arguments to __init__ if you want.
        # ----------------------- ADD YOUR CODE HERE --------------------------
        self.conv1_1 = nn.Conv3d(in_channels = 1, out_channels = 4, kernel_size = 3, stride = 1, padding = 0)
        self.relu1_1 = nn.ReLU()
        self.conv2_1 = nn.Conv3d(in_channels = 4, out_channels = 4, kernel_size = 3, stride = 1, padding = 0)
        self.bnn1_1 = nn.BatchNorm3d(num_features = 4)
        self.relu2_1 = nn.ReLU()
        self.maxp1_1 = nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size = 2, stride=2, padding=0)

        self.conv1_2 = nn.Conv3d(in_channels = 4, out_channels = 8, kernel_size = 3, stride = 1, padding = 0)
        self.relu1_2 = nn.ReLU()
        self.conv2_2 = nn.Conv3d(in_channels = 8, out_channels = 8, kernel_size = 3, stride = 1, padding = 0)
        self.bnn1_2 = nn.BatchNorm3d(num_features = 8)
        self.relu2_2 = nn.ReLU()
        self.maxp1_2 = nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size = 2, stride=2, padding=0)

        self.conv1_3 = nn.Conv3d(in_channels = 8, out_channels = 16, kernel_size = 3, stride = 1, padding = 0)
        self.relu1_3 = nn.ReLU()
        self.conv2_3 = nn.Conv3d(in_channels = 16, out_channels = 16, kernel_size = 3, stride = 1, padding = 0)
        self.bnn1_3 = nn.BatchNorm3d(num_features = 16)
        self.relu2_3 = nn.ReLU()
        self.maxp1_3 = nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size = 2, stride=2, padding=0)

        self.conv1_4 = nn.Conv3d(in_channels = 16, out_channels = 32, kernel_size = 3, stride = 1, padding = 0)
        self.relu1_4 = nn.ReLU()
        self.conv2_4 = nn.Conv3d(in_channels = 32, out_channels = 32, kernel_size = 3, stride = 1, padding = 0)
        self.bnn1_4 = nn.BatchNorm3d(num_features = 32)
        self.relu2_4 = nn.ReLU()
        self.maxp1_4 = nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size = 2, stride=2, padding=0)

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(2048, 1)
        self.relu1_5 = nn.ReLU()

       
        # ------------------------------- END ---------------------------------

    def forward(self, imgs: Tensor) -> Tensor:
        """
        Forward pass of your model.

        :param imgs: Batch of input images. Shape (N, 1, H, W, D)
        :return pred: Batch of predicted ages. Shape (N)
        """
        # ----------------------- ADD YOUR CODE HERE --------------------------
       

        x = self.relu1_1(self.conv1_1(imgs))
        x = self.maxp1_1(self.relu2_1(self.bnn1_1(self.conv2_1(x))))

        x = self.relu1_2(self.conv1_2(x))
        x = self.maxp1_2(self.relu2_2(self.bnn1_2(self.conv2_2(x))))

        x = self.relu1_3(self.conv1_3(x))
        x = self.maxp1_3(self.relu2_3(self.bnn1_3(self.conv2_3(x))))

        x = self.relu1_4(self.conv1_4(x))
        x = self.maxp1_4(self.relu2_4(self.bnn1_4(self.conv2_4(x))))

        x = x.view(-1, x.shape[0]*x.shape[1]*x.shape[2]*x.shape[3]*x.shape[4])
        pred = self.relu1_5(self.fc1(x))
        
        # ------------------------------- END ---------------------------------
        return pred

    def train_step(
        self,
        imgs: Tensor,
        labels: Tensor,
        return_prediction: Optional[bool] = False
    ):
        """Perform a training step. Predict the age for a batch of images and
        return the loss.

        :param imgs: Batch of input images (N, 1, H, W, D)
        :param labels: Batch of target labels (N)
        :return loss: The current loss, a single scalar.
        :return pred
        """
        pred = torch.squeeze(self.forward(imgs.float()))  # (N)

        # ----------------------- ADD YOUR CODE HERE --------------------------
        
        loss = self.loss(labels.float(), pred)

        # ------------------------------- END ---------------------------------

        if return_prediction:
            return loss, pred
        else:
            return loss
```

Any help you can give me will be welcomed.

I tried changing the batch size, but it gives the same error but with other values of matrix multiplication.

I am expecting a training in Google Colab of the neural network: getting a scalar value from a input image of size (8,1,96,96,96), but without any error.

Answer (score 0):

From error it looks like that validate inside train has the error. and This means that you should look at your dataloader (you have two, train and validate dataloader dataloaders['train'] and ['val']), if you are using the batch for both, maybe the size of data for your validation set is not multiple of batchsize and last batch is not complete. you could use drop_last in your DataLoader to ignore last one.

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html

Answer (score 0):

For those coming for this answer for LLM inference that works on Colab but not working on locally:

- Make sure your torch version cuda is same as installed cuda version (bitsandbytes uses it).
- Check your torch version with  torch.**version**
- check which CUDA version your path shows up `CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda`
  usually cuda is symbolic link

> ```
> ls -altr /usr/local/cuda
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Tem  2 11:45 /usr/local/cuda -> /usr/local/cuda-11.8/
> ```

- Make sure you do not accidentally install torch or libraries to other installation path if you are not using virtual environment (e.g. pip install and pip3 install may install to different paths)
- nvidia-smi reports installed graphic driver cuda version not actuall cuda installed

**4 bit LLM loading problems (falcon, alpaca etc) (that give this shape cannot be multiplied error)**

- For running 4 bit models with configuration like following:

> ```
> bnb_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(
>     load_in_4bit=True,
>     bnb_4bit_quant_type="nf4",
>     bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=torch.float16,
> )
>
> model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
>     model_name,
>     quantization_config=bnb_config,
>     trust_remote_code=True,
> )
> ```

- print your model and check for linear layers
  if you are up to use 4 bit there should be Linear4bit  layers instead of Linear.. If you do not see Linear4bit layers then your base model is not loaded as 4bit and likely you cannot use Lora with it and will get mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied errors..
- For solution check for any bugs/loading problems on peft and bitsandbytes libraries.